# Why does it not see the integer even though they are in the same class?

Tags: android-studio, int

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int loop = 1;
    int points = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    for(loop == 1);{//the error is here

    }
    public void click(){
        points++;
    }

}
```

it doesnt see loop(int) and I don`t know why.

I am trying to make a clicker game, so more tips would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing your code outside the onCreate method. The code must either be within the onCreate() or inside another function.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int loop = 1;
int points = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for(loop == 1){
        //write your code here
    }
}

public void click(){
    points++;
}
```

}